# Why GET method can be used to submit the form data?

Tags: html, rest, http, web, get

As we know, the form data in html can be submitted through GET method or POST method.
But in Http RFC, it is said that 
*In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval*.

Then why can we submit form data to the server through GET method? Should GET method just be used to retrieval?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be operating under the misconception that a form can't be used for information retrieval.

There are forms where the information entered by the user is used to decide what information to retrieve. The information isn't stored anywhere (at least not in a fashion that is *significant*, e.g. it might be logged).

An example of a form of this nature is the big one on the homepage of any search engine (like Google or Duckduckgo).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is quite helpful.